# Implement add-ons doPost and doGet triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

is it possible create a gas add-ons that makes it possible implement doGet and doPost triggers?
If I can, how can I get the /exec url?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. The exec URL is the same for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Url is provided to you when you publish your Application.

Read the documentation on doPost and doGet here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web